# Need to understand branch tracking

Tags: git

I have written other questions about tracking but I think I have poorly explained what I do not understand. Here is a quick example in order to show my problem:

- I created a Gitlab project.
- I cloned this project on my computer with `git clone`.
- I created a new branch in the Gitlab web interface (with the '+' button): `my_server_branch`.
- I put a single file into this branch (also with the web interface).

So, at this step, my computer doesn't know anything about `my_server_branch`.

I have read I should create a "tracking branch" on my computer with:

```
git branch --track my_server_branch origin/my_server_branch
```

I have not run this command. I simply typed (on master branch, on my computer):

```
git pull
```

And here is what i see in the console:

```
 * [new branch]      my_server_branch -> origin/my_server_branch
```

So git detects there is a new branch when i launch a pull. So, again, my question is: What is the advantage of tracking the branch if gits detects and do the stuff ?

There is certainly an advantage to track because if not, this command wont exists... but I do not see this advantage.

And if i type the `git branch --track` command, here is what i get:

```
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/my_server_branch' does not exist
```

Comment: because it's already tracking

Comment: So maybe git has automaticly sets tracking during my git pull ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of concepts here that you need to keep separate in your head; and then there is a terminology issue as well.

These are the concepts:

- *branch names* like `master`;
- *remote-tracking* names—often called *remote-tracking branches*—like `origin/master`;
- the idea of an *upstream;* and
- *commits*, which are identified by their *hash IDs;* hold files plus some *metadata;* and, via that metadata, form chains.

The first two—branch names and remote-tracking names—are pretty closely related, and, along with tag names like `v2.1`, are all grouped into one concept that Git calls a *reference*.

The terminology problem is that sometimes, some branches—some names like `master`—are said to be *tracking*.  Other names like `origin/master` are called *remote-tracking branches*, which looks like it's the same thing.  It's not!  That's why I call the latter *remote-tracking names*, to avoid the word *branch*, and why I recommend that instead of the verb *tracking*, you think about branch names like `master` as either *having an upstream* or *not having an upstream*.  This sidesteps the tricky word *track* (which has yet another meaning when applied to files in your work-tree).

Let's move on here to your actions:

> Here is a quick example in order to show my problem:
>
> - I have created a gitlab project
> - I have cloned this project on my computer with `git clone` command

At this point, you have two separate repositories.  There's one on the GitLab server computer, and one on your own computer.  We'll call the GitLab one "theirs" and the one on your computer "yours", even though in a sense, they are both yours.  Your repository is very similar to theirs, but not exactly the same: it's a clone, and it has a way to identify it as the copy instead of the original.

We'll come back to your repository, on your computer, in a bit.  The next few steps all happen in *their* repository though.

> - Then, i have created a new branch in gitlab web interface (with the '+' button): `my_server_branch`

OK, so at this point, *their* Git repository has a branch that yours does not know about.

> - I have put a single file into this branch (also with gitlab web interface)

Technically, you can't put a *file* into a repository like this.  What you did is add a new *commit*, with the new commit containing the file.

This matters because the way branch names work is to remember the hash ID of the *last* commit that goes in the branch.  When you add a new commit, the hash ID stored in the branch name changes to remember the new commit.  The new commit remembers the previous last-commit.

If we draw these out, using single uppercase letters to stand in for the actual commit hash IDs, we get a picture like this one for a simple three-commit repository with just a `master` branch:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master
```

Here, the *name* `master` remembers the actual hash ID of commit `C`.  That commit itself remembers the actual hash ID of commit `B`, which remembers the hash ID of commit `A`.  So Git only needs to have the name `master` remember commit `C`'s ID: the rest, it finds by looking at the commits themselves.

(We say that `master` *points to* `C`, and `C` points to `B` and `B` points to `A`.  Since `A` is the very first commit ever made in the repository, it points nowhere: that's what tells us, and Git, that we can stop and rest.  There's no previous history to examine.  The commits *are* the history, and history goes *C then B then A*.)

To add a new branch to a repository, we typically pick some existing commit inside the repository and check it out, so that it's the current commit, then add a new name that points to that same commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, my_server_branch (HEAD)
```

Git needs to know *which name* to update when we make new commits, so Git attaches the special name `HEAD` (in all uppercase like this) to a branch name.  If we're using the local computer (rather than the web interface), we would then create a file, use `git add` to add it, and run `git commit` to make the new commit.  If we're using the web interface, GitLab pretty much does the same thing in *their* repository, it's just hidden behind their web interface.  They end up with:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- my_server_branch (HEAD)
```

although they may do it in such a way that they leave `HEAD` attached to `master` anyway.  That's how GitHub would do it, for instance, without moving `HEAD`.  In any case, since it's *their* `HEAD`, not yours, it's not all that important right now.

#### Clones get their own branches

Now it's time to look back at your own repository.  When you ran:

```
git clone <url>
```

you had your computer make a new, empty Git repository, with *no* commits, *no* branches, basically nothing but the empty repository shell.  Then you had your Git on your computer fill in that shell by grabbing *all* the commits from *their* Git.  So if they had three simple commits:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

your Git got those three commits:

```
A--B--C
```

(the internal, backwards-pointing arrows are too annoying to draw, but they're still there: `C` points to `B` and `B` points to `A`).

The hash IDs all match: every Git in the universe will agree that whatever is inside commit `C`, that makes its hash ID `C`'s hash ID.  So your Git and their Git can tell which Git has which commits, just by looking at these hash IDs.  But *your* Git still doesn't have any branches yet.

Your Git asks their Git what all their branch and tag names are, and they say: *My `master` holds the hash ID for commit `C`.*  So your Git now creates, not `master`, but rather `origin/master`, pointing to commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- origin/master
```

There are no commits and no branches left, so your Git is done copying.  Your Git now does the last step of `git clone`, which is to run:

```
git checkout master
```

You can make your Git use some other name, and if you don't, your Git asks *their* Git which name to use; but that's the usual, common case: your Git tries to check  out your `master`.

***You don't have a `master`.***  And yet, this checkout succeeds anyway.  The reason it succeeds is that *their* Git had a `master` and *your* Git copied that to *your* `origin/master`.  So your Git, instead of just failing the checkout, says to itself: *Hm, there's no `master`, but there's `origin/master` ... that looks a lot like `master`, I bet you meant that I should **make** `master` using `origin/master`.*  So your Git does that:

```
git checkout --track master origin/master
```

which *creates* your own `master`, and sets its *upstream* to `origin/master`.  So now you have this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

Your `master` branch exists now and has `origin/master` as its upstream.

#### Sidebar: if you're confused, rest assured, this is confusing!

The confusing way to put this is that your `master` branch (1) is now tracking (2) your remote-tracking branch (3, 4, 5) `origin/master` from remote (6) `origin`.  Here, at points (1) and (5), both words or phrases use the word *branch*, but both mean something different.  At (2) and (4) we have the word *tracking*, both meaning something different.  At (3) and (6) we have the word *remote*, both meaning something different.  You can see why I don't like these words, and prefer to call this the *branch name* `master`, with the *upstream* `origin/master`, with `origin/master` being a *remote-tracking name* associated with the *remote* `origin`.  I still have to use the word *remote* twice, but "remote-tracking" is at least hyphenated.

#### One right and good way to get `my_server_branch` locally

Having made `my_server_branch` in *their* Git, and added commit `D` there, what you can do now is run the command:

```
git fetch
```

in your own Git on your computer.  (You can use `git fetch origin` if you want to be explicit.)  This has your Git call up their Git and ask it, again, for its list of branch names.  This time they say: *I have `master`, at commit `C`.  I have `my_server_branch`, at commit `D`.*  Your Git says: *Ah, I already have commit `C`, so no problem there.  Give me commit `D` though.*  They do that, and now the conversation between your Git and their Git is done.  Now your Git updates your `origin/master` to point to `C`—that's no change at all—and *creates* your `origin/my_server_branch`, pointing to new commit `D`.  So now you have:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
       \
        D   <-- origin/my_server_branch
```

You can now run `git checkout my_server_branch`.  As before, **you don't have a `my_server_branch`** at the moment, but instead of just failing, your Git will say: *Aha, I don't have `my_server_branch`.  But I do have `origin/my_server_branch`.  I'll **create** `my_server_branch`, pointing to commit `D`.  I'll set the upstream of `my_server_branch` to be `origin/my_server_branch`.  Then I'll do the checkout you asked for.*  The result is:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        D   <-- my_server_branch (HEAD), origin/my_server_branch
```

#### You almost never need to use `git checkout --track`

The only time you do need `git checkout --track` is when `git checkout` won't do the right thing for you.  This happens in two cases:

- Suppose you have more than one *remote*, e.g., if you have `origin` plus a second remote `fred` for getting stuff from Fred's repository.  Suppose further that you have your own `origin/hello` copied from the branch `hello` on origin, and Fred has *Fred's* `hello` which is now copied to your `fred/hello`.  If you try to `git checkout hello`, your Git will find *two* candidates—`fred/hello` and `origin/hello`—and not know which one to use.  So now you can run instead:

  ```
  git checkout --track fred/hello
  ```

  if you really meant to use Fred's, or:

  ```
  git checkout --track origin/hello
  ```

  if you really meant to use origin's.
- Or, if for some strange reason, you have, say, `origin/my_server_branch`, but in *your* repository, you want to call this `bob_server_branch`.  Using `git checkout my_server_branch` gets you `my_server_branch`; and of course, using `git checkout bob_server_branch` tries to find `origin/bob_server_branch`.  So here, you need the long form:

  ```
  git checkout --track bob_server_branch origin/my_server_branch
  ```

#### About `git pull`

The `git pull` command is shorthand for:

- run `git fetch`; then, provided that succeeds
- run a second Git command, usually `git merge`.

Since `git fetch` will (when run with the right options, anyway) *create and/or update* your `origin/*` remote-tracking names from `origin`'s branches, it's the first half of `git pull` that made `origin/my_server_branch` for you.

The second command—the `git merge`, or, if you tell it to use `git rebase` instead, the `git rebase`—takes commits brought in *by* the first command and uses those to merge, or to rebase.

I don't like the `git pull` command, for a number of reasons, some of which are purely historical (`git pull` used to occasionally destroy your local work in a few rare but not unheard-of cases, and I had that happen to me at least once).  The most practical objection is pretty simple though: until you see what `git fetch` fetched, *how do you know whether you want to run `git merge`, `git rebase`, or something else entirely?*  So I prefer to avoid `git pull`: I run `git fetch` first, then *maybe* run a `git merge` or `git rebase`, or maybe do something else entirely.  What to do depends on what I saw from `git fetch` (and also what I'm doing with this particular repository, of course).

There are a few, occasion exceptions, especially with repositories that I use read-only—I just want their latest commit plus its history, so `git pull` is *probably* fine, as long as *they* behave well—or where I control both ends, e.g., the `origin` repository is really mine over on GitHub, and I *know* what I put in there.  But even for the latter case, I tend to avoid `git pull`, because sometimes I forget what I've put into which repository.  Using `git fetch` lets me check first.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In short answer we can say that git checkout does the —track work for me in my case ?

Comment: It does, as long as it invokes what Git calls the "DWIM" code for this case. That is, as long as the branch doesn't exist, but is being created from a remote-tracking name, the default is to set it up the way you want. (But note that you can override the default, either on the command line or in your Git configuration.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, but the advantage to tracking a remote branch is that you can push to and pull from it.

Check out the branch locally:
`git checkout my_server_branch`

Make changes and commit.

Now `git push` will push your changes to the remote `origin/my_server_branch` branch.

Comment: I have made push and pull without typing --track command. This is what i do not understand

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` runs `git fetch` and `git merge`. Just nice to know

With the first part of this command (`git fetch`) you fetched all the branches from the remote. As you can read [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), this command fetches all the `refs`.

By default, when you check out a new branch from remote, git will create it as a new upstream branch. Basically, the command you are asking about was run for you implicitly, when you fetched all the branches.